# Routing API requests to Node Server in MEAN app while deploying in server

Tags: node.js, angular, nginx, mean-stack

I'm deploying my `MEAN` app in a subdomain `https://app.example.com`

Here is my app folder structure

```
app
 - frontend (Angular Code)
 - backend (NodeJS Code)
```

The server is running on NGINX, here are the config details:

```
 server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name app.example.com;
    root /var/www/app/frontend/dist;

    index index.html;
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$query_string;
    } 

}
```

I'm running my NodeJS code in port 8080 in the same subdomain. 
Log shows that the server is running on the port successfully.

But when my app makes API requests from the Angular App, the requests are getting timed out.

I guess it's because of the routing in the config file, how do I make the API requests route through my NodeJS code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to forward requests from nginx to your app. Currently your server is doing nothing, except serving html files. Read nginx docs or look for tutorials regarding proxy_pass setting.

Currently you can just add this to your nginx and it will fire up

```
. . .
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

}

Comment: should i add these lines below `try_files `?

Comment: doesn't matter really, try_files is just telling nginx to serve these files. But why would you want to serve html files? Let nodejs serve them as an application. So I think if you have no real reason for it and you do not 100% understand the objective, just exclude it and leave what I gave you.